# Get quote data(Shipping zip code) from observer magento 2

Tags: magento2, quote, sales-quote

I created a observer and i need to fetch the zip code of current quote, Below code is for my event.xml

```
<event name="sales_quote_collect_totals_before">
<observer name="sipl_oda_observer_observer" instance="Sys\Oda\Observer\Observer" />
</event>
```

Code for Observer.php

```
$order= $observer->getData('order');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Comment: can you please share your module. I am also looking for the same. It would be more helpful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can  not  get ***order object `$order` from  this observer.***

This observer only able to give u ***Quote Object*** mean **Cart object**

> $this->eventManager->dispatch(
>               'sales_quote_collect_totals_before',
>               ['quote' => $quote]
>           );

So, At Observer files, you cab *get Quote object*

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
```

from this Quote object you can get ***Cart item details ,billing and shipping address,payments   method details etc of a Cart***